# Paperclip is throwing a strange error all of a sudden after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I can no longer render pages with paperclip urls in my Rails application. I recently updated my gem bundle. I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and Paperclip 3.1.4. I was using Paperclip 2.7.0 before.

The link in my view that is failing is:

```
ad.image.url(:medium)
```

My Ad model has these declarations:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :ad_subdomain do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.brand.subdomain
end

has_attached_file :image, 
                :default_url => '/images/blank.gif',
                :styles => { :medium => ["290x230>","jpg"],
                             :thumb => ["100x100>","jpg"] },
                :storage => :file,
                :path => "/mcp/ads/:style/:ad_subdomain/:basename.:extension"
```

The error that is being thrown is:

```
TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mcp5/gems/paperclip-3.1.4/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:368:in `extend'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mcp5/gems/paperclip-3.1.4/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:368:in `initialize_storage'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mcp5/gems/paperclip-3.1.4/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:80:in `initialize'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mcp5/gems/paperclip-3.1.4/lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:5:in `new'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mcp5/gems/paperclip-3.1.4/lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:5:in `attachment_for'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mcp5/gems/paperclip-3.1.4/lib/paperclip.rb:191:in `block in has_attached_file'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For some reason, I had:

```
:storage => :file
```

in my declaration. That does not work. If you want to use the filesystem, you just leave out the storage line altogether and it will default.

Comment: That is strange, I had a similar problem and this solved it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the requirements listed on the Paperclip github page:

> Paperclip now requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2 and Rails version >= 3.0
>   (Only if you're going to use Paperclip with Ruby on Rails.)
>
> If you're still on Ruby 1.8.7 or Ruby on Rails 2.3.x, you can still
>   use Paperclip 2.7.x with your project. Also, everything in this README
>   might not apply to your version of Paperclip, and you should read the
>   README for version 2.7 instead.

Comment: Thank Benjamin. I misspoke. I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and Ruby 1.9.3. I have edited my question.